# Laravel old images are not deleting using getOriginal method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel 7 project, I am renaming images on the upload based on the Station `name` field. Converting a string to slug using `Str::of($name)->slug()` see below

Naming the image

```
public function setStationName($extension, $name)
{
    return 'station-' . Str::of($name)->slug() . '.' . $extension;
}
```

So it will generate a name like `station-foo-bar.png` and finally storing this name to the `photo` column to database.

Since the `name` field is editable so the user will be able to change the name field at any time and if the user is uploading a new image with the name field modified, the new image will have a new name.

#### Here I am getting trouble.

While updating the record with new image and modified field, if I delete the older image using the `getOriginal('photo)` method, it is not deleting the image. However, it deletes the image if the `name` field isn't modified.

## Station Model

```
public function deletePhoto()
{
    Storage::disk('public')->delete($this->stationPhotoDir . '/' . $this->getOriginal('photo'));
}
```

When I `dd` to check the value of `getOriginal('photo')` it is returning the correct filename that I want to delete but it is not deleting.

> **Question:**
>
> How to delete old images using the `getOriginal()` method?

Comment: did you call the `getOriginal` before saving in the database ? can you show us where did you call `deletePhoto` ?

Comment: @Maraboc yes I am doing that right before any other code in update method. It is on the very first line.

Comment: @Maraboc Oh my bad. Very stupid mistake. By looking in the folder I found it is deleting the image. However, I have more sizes that I have to delete separately and here I misunderstood and overlooked. This means there is no issue with `getOriginal` but my stupid misunderstanding. Therefore the question doesn't deserve to be here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't `getOriginal`, it's the path that is incorrect in the delete operation.

Add `Log::info($this->stationPhotoDir . '/' . $this->getOriginal('photo'))` and see what the path says.